# How to scale around point using BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I've searched but haven't found anyone wanting to do this with a bitmapData object.

I'm using the following code:

```
matrix.identity();
matrix.translate(pan.x, pan.y);
matrix.translate(-zoomPoint.x, -zoomPoint.y);
matrix.scale(scale, scale);
matrix.translate(zoomPoint.x, zoomPoint.y);

// later my draw call
this.bitmapData.draw(srcBitmap, matrix, null, null, null, true);
```

pan is a Point containing translation values
scale contains 0..1
zoomPoint is a Point containing a mouse click

Panning works, but using this method scale does not scale around my mouse.  Has anyone done this successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix will translate the scale first, so you might have to take that into account when you set the translation.  I needed to scale and select an area previously, and came up with this: [BitmapData - scale and select area in one matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520157/bitmapdata-scale-and-select-area-in-one-matrix)

Comment: I wanna be shanethehat!  That's sweet.  Thank you, I'll check out your link.

Answer (score 0):

This Works:

var scale:Number = 0.32;

var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.scale(scale, scale);

var smallBMD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bigBMD.width * scale, bigBMD.height * scale, true, 0x000000);

smallBMD.draw(bigBMD, matrix, null, null, null, true);

var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(smallBMD, PixelSnapping.NEVER, true);

Comment: Thanks!  Though this doesn't add a translation to the bitmap.  It's the combination of translation / scaling that is messing up my output.